# Accessing the Element Type of a Generic Collection that Acts as an Upper Bound

Tags: java, generics

I want to write a generic container class. The two type parameters stand for the type of the contained elements, and a key type to look up elements. The collection features a `get` method that takes a key and returns an element. So a first signature for the class would be like this:

```
class MyContainer<E, K> {
  ...
  E get(K k) { ...}
  ...
}
```

Now I want to constrain `K` to classes that are themselves container for elements that I want to use as keys.

These key-containing classes are designated by implementing a certain interface:

```
interface ProvidesKeys<E> {...}
```

and then I have concrete implementations like

```
class SomeInts implements ProvidesKeys<Integer> {...}
```

meaning that `SomeInts` selects some elements from Integer that can be used as keys.

I want to use `MyContainer` like this:

```
MyContainer<String, SomeInts> myContainer = new MyContainer<>();
...
myContainer.get(3);
```

The problem is that `3` is of type `Integer`, not `SomeInts`. So my initial scheme for MyContainer does not work anymore.

Is there a way to constrain `K` in such a way that I have access to the key container's element type?

I've tried

```
class MyContainer<E, K extends ProvidesKeys<K> {....}
```

and wildcard forms, but nothing gives me access to the element type of the key providing-type, so I could have a correct `E get(X k) {...}` method!? Do I have to introduce a third type variable to represent the key element type (although it is implicit in the key container)?

Comment: Looking at your desired usage of `MyContainer`, I don't see how `SomeInts` is relevant at all. Why not just do `MyContainer<String, Integer> myContainer = ...`? What is `SomeInts` used for?

Comment: How about introducing a third generic parameter? `class MyContainer<E, K, KC extends ProvidesKeys<K>> {`?

Comment: You said you want to constrain your keys to classes that are containers. 3 is not a container, so your goal is not realistic.

Comment: @sweeper The challenge is that keys could be as diverse as integer, chars or enums. Maybe a third type parameter is my only option. Post an answer to that end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I have to introduce a third type variable to represent the key element type (although it is implicit in the key container)?

Yes.  You do.  There is no other way to access that type other than to have it be a parameter.